# Calculate the volume enclosed by $x^\frac{1}{3}+y^\frac{1}{3}+z^\frac{1}{3}=a^\frac{1}{3}$?

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral, jacobian

I have to calculate the volume inside the area of $x^\frac{1}{3}+y^\frac{1}{3}+z^\frac{1}{3}=a^\frac{1}{3}$. I figured i should replace x, y and z with something like the spherical coordinates but not quite. My idea was to change them with the same as they are but then to the power of $\frac{1}{6}$ and recalculate the jacobian from here. Is this the good way to go or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sounds reasonable enough.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) what do you mean by "the volume inside an area" and 2) I've tried to graph your implicit equation and it never gives a closed volume.

Comment: 1) the area inside whatever that function is (i think some kind of sphere) 2) i changed the values because i have to do this as an assingment but I want to understand it, the original values where $\frac{2}{3}$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @R.vW, with $\frac{2}{3}$, the object depicted is closed and then you can calculate its volume, but not with $\frac{1}{3}$ where the surface doesn't "close in" into itself, so there is no volume to calculate.

Comment: Then do you have another example where i could find out what i should do here?

Comment: What's wrong with $2\over3$?

Comment: Well i fought if i have a example then i could try doing it myself for my assignment but sure $\frac{2}{3}$ works as well

Comment: @R.vW . If you want one that looks like your example, try $\frac{4}{3}$ or any exponent of the form $\frac{2n}{3}$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining where i should start here because i have no idea

Comment: I would do exactly what you said in the original post. In the case of $\frac{2}{3}$, let $u,v,w$ play the role of standard spherical coordinates. Then let $u = x^{2/3}, v = y^{2/3}, w = z^{2/3}$. Raise the resulting three equations to the $\frac{3}{2}$ power to get in terms of $x,y,z$, then calculate the Jacobian determinant, and integrate

Comment: Should it not be to power of $\frac{1}{3}$ as normally all varbles are to the power of 2?